# What is the difference between StartDate > DateAdd(dd,-1,@EndDate) and StartDate >=@EndDate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between this

```
StartDate > DateAdd(dd,-1,@EndDate)
```

and this

```
StartDate >=@EndDate
```

Comment: There is no difference ? Why do You ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same *if* `StartDate` and `EndDate` have a `date` data type.

If they a time component then the logic is different.

Consider:

```
EndDate    2017-05-09 11:00:00
```

Then the first gets everything *after* 2017-05-08 11:00:00.

The second gets everything *on or after* 2017-05-09 11:00:00.  Clearly, these are different.

I should also add:  When using date parts, spell out the full name of the date part.  So use this:

```
StartDate > DateAdd(day, -1, @EndDate)
```

rather than using `dd`.  This makes the code easier to read.  It also prevent problems with abbreviations.  Is `mm` for minutes or months?  Is `ms` for milliseconds or microseconds?  Why bother trying to remember?